# How to get npm to update without having to re-build?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, npm, vue.js

I'm trying to get get it so that I don't have to re-build with npm every time I make changes.  I'm working with Vue.js as my front-end framework, and Python-Flask for my MT.

When I was first working with Vue, I was just messing around and had no MT code.  I had the following in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5000 --open --hot",
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
},
```

Running:

```
npm run dev
```

Would open up a browser window with the hosted Vue application, and would automatically update anytime I made changes.

Now that I've added Flask to the mix, I already have the application hosted with Flask, and I just want my Vue application to auto-refresh as I'm working on it.  Currently, the only thing that works is to build after every change, which is quite tedious.

I don't really know npm very well, and I can't seem to find any documentation on this.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for watch mode? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/

Comment: Are you accessing your application at 127.0.0.1:5000?

Comment: @k0pernikus, I have been unable to get nodemon to work properly.

Comment: @Lucas, I am accessing my application at 127.0.0.1:5000

Comment: @drewkroft You may want to ask a dedicated question to your nodemon problem. It's unlikely that your question in its current state will generate an answer.